# Node Nestjs watch always break?

Tags: node.js, npm, nestjs

I am new to node js development. I am using nestjs framework.
I have annoying problem that whenever run

```
npm run start:debug
```

in package.json

```
 "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
```

after some changes it break with the following error. How can I fix that?

It doesn't break right away it does when I start writing some code then delete some then it breaks out.

Thanks in advance :))

```
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn ps ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:269:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:465:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:465:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn ps',
  path: 'ps',
  spawnargs: [ '-o', 'pid', '--no-headers', '--ppid', 35 ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! clinic@0.0.1 start:debug: `nest start --debug --watch`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the clinic@0.0.1 start:debug script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/node/.npm/_logs/2020-11-30T15_57_08_124Z-debug.log
```

Docker File

```
FROM node:14-slim

RUN adduser node sudo

RUN npm i -g @nestjs/cli

RUN apt-get -yq update  
RUN apt-get -yq install openssl 

USER node
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't write any code yet. This is just plain new install of nestjs. 
Though I am using docker image node:14-slim.

Comment: If I were sitting at your computer trying to figure this out, I'd look at your package.json to see what the start:debug script is doing.  I'd try running that command manually.  I'd trim down whatever main js file it is running to just a console.log('hello') message and see if it runs (to see if it's something systemic).  Then I'd re-run an npm install just to make sure everything is present and up to date. Then I'd gradually start adding code back in until I find the problem again.  Remove things until I found the line that causes the exception. I need more info.  Is this a create-react-app?

Comment: @mahmoudmagdy: can you include the error stacktrace?

Comment: I added the stack trace to the question

Answer (score 6):

node:[version] images are based on fullblown buildpack-deps:*-scm images.
node:*-slim images depend on debian:*-slim.

[buildpack-deps scm](https://github.com/docker-library/buildpack-deps/blob/master/Dockerfile-scm.template) includes procps, that [includes ps](https://packages.debian.org/en/stretch/procps), which the tsc watch mode depends on for whatever reason to find it's child processes.

Add to stick with the slim image, just add procps install to your Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update; \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests -q -y procps
```

Also, you should cleanup after that install, to get those ~19M down to ~3M, if you don't want all those lists and logs around and keep it 'slim':

```
RUN apt-get update; \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests -q -y \
        procps \
        ; \
    apt-get autoremove -y; \
    apt-get clean; \
    rm -rf \
        /var/cache/apt/archives \
        /var/cache/ldconfig/* \
        /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
        /var/log/alternatives.log \
        /var/log/apt/* \
        /var/log/dpkg.log
```

Comment: This one saved me a lot of time, I was using debian based image (ubuntu)

Answer (score 3):

I changed node-slim image to node in docker file and it worked fine. It seems that there is a problem with slim image.